# A value of type 'RenderObject' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RenderBox'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 void getPositions() {
  final RenderBox renderBox = scheduleForDayKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject();
  final position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  print("POSITION of Red: $position ");
}
```

This part is underlined with red:

```
scheduleForDayKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()
```

When I hover, it tells me the error:

> A value of type 'RenderObject' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'RenderBox'.

Maybe this section of code is outdated or something because I see a lot of similar code examples on the internet, which for some reason don't work for me.

Comment: The examples no longer work because Dart with null-safety enabled no longer allows implicit downcasts.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try writing:

```
final RenderBox renderBox = scheduleForDayKey.currentContext!
                                             .findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
```

Answer (score 10):

for me this code work with my for   sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject()  as RenderBox;

Answer (score 1):

final renderbox = context!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

Comment: Please provide an explanation and improve your formatting. See [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).